# How to install the latest awesome window manager?

Tags: software-installation, awesome

How do I install the latest `awesome` window manager on Ubuntu?

For example,

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS contains awesome 3.5.6
- Ubuntu 16.10 contains awesome 3.5.9

but the latest release as of now is 4.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an unofficial [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~klaus-vormweg/+archive/ubuntu/awesome) for `awesome` window manager. You can run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:klaus-vormweg/awesome -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install  awesome -y
```

This will install the latest `awesome` (currently version 4.0) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS, 16.10, or 18.04 LTS.